# AT command to change phone number

Tags: at-command

Is there a way to change the number broadcast of a cellphone via an AT command?

e.g.
Cellphone number: 0123456798 but I want to broadcast 0000.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to change the number being broadcast. Some modules have an "engineering mode" which allows for some additional features, but the cellular number is decided by the sim card.